# nested if else for string search

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, grepl

Reproduceable dataset

```
   data1 <- data.frame(ID = c(1,2), Description = c("Chiquita","Chiquita mazamorra"), Max = c(200,125))
   data2 <- data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7), Description = c("Chiquita mini", "Chiquita Oriville","Chiquita 24h","Manzano Chiquita 5j...","Chiquita mazamorra 1,2h..","Chiquita mazamorra Buro","Chiquita AM 2F"), Max = c(24,110,80,90,134,123,210))
```

I have a dataset , data1, as shown below

```
  Id     Description            Max
  1      Chiquita               200
  2      Chiquita mazamorra     125
```

I have another dataset, data2, as shown below

```
  Id     Description                   Actual
  1      Chiquita mini                 24
  2      Chiquita Oriville             110
  3      Chiquita 24h                  80
  4      Manzano Chiquita 5j...        90
  5      Chiquita mazamorra 1,2h...    134
  6      Chiquita mazamorra Buro       123
  7      Chiquita AM 2F                210
  8      Chiquita.....                 124
  9      Chiquita(P)                   213
  10     Chiquita, mazamorra, S        188
```

If statement should check if the Data2 Description contains this character in data2$Description **Chiquita mazamorra**, if yes then check if Data2$Actual > Data1$Max. If Yes then Results == Good, else Small. Note there can be other characters after Chiquita mazamorra like for example **Chiquita mazamorra 1,2h..** this is okay, but  not **Chiquita mazamorra Buro**

Similarly another ifelse should check if the Data2 Description contains **Chiquita** if yes then check if Data2$Actual > Data1$Max. If Yes then Results == Good, else Small. There can be other characters after Chiquita like for example **Chiquita 24h** or **Chiquita AM 2F** these are okay but not **Chiquita mini** or **Chiquita Oriville**

This is the final desired output (data2)

```
  Id     Description                   Actual      Result
  1      Chiquita mini                 24          NA
  2      Chiquita Oriville             110         NA
  3      Chiquita 24h                  80          Small
  4      Manzano Chiquita 5j...        90          NA
  5      Chiquita mazamorra 1,2h...    134         Good         
  7      Chiquita mazamorra Buro       123         NA
  6      Chiquita AM 2F                210         Good
  8      Chiquita.....                 124         Small
  9      Chiquita(P)                   213         NA
  10     Chiquita, mazamorra, S        188         Good
```

I have know this can be done using a combination of grepl and ifelse statements I am not very confident ? Maybe there is a better way of doing this, I dont know, I am getting very confused. Need help.

Comment: Please provide reproducible example if you really need help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Here's a general outline of a solution

```
data1 <- read.csv(text=
"Id,Description,Max
1,Chiquita,200
2,Chiquita mazamorra,125")

data2 <- read.csv(text=
"Id,Description,Actual
1,Chiquita mini,24
2,Chiquita Oriville,110
3,Chiquita 24h,80
4,Manzano Chiquita 5j,90
5,Chiquita mazamorra 12h,134
6,Chiquita mazamorra Buro,123
7,Chiquita AM 2F,210")


# start by trimming the description to the first few words 
# that don't start with a number
data2$Description_trimmed <- gsub('\\s+\\d.*$','',data2$Description)

# initialize the output field
data2$Results <- NA

# loop while there are missing values in data$Results
while(any(is.na(data2$Results))){

    # identify records that still need to be calculated
    indx <- is.na(data2$Results)

    # calculate the result based on the current trimmed description
    data2[indx,'Results']  <-  ifelse(
                data2[indx,'Actual']  < 
                    data1[match(data2[indx,'Description_trimmed'],
                                data1[    ,'Description']),
                          "Max"],
                'Good',
                'Small')

    # trim the last word from Description_trimmed
    data2$Description_trimmed <- gsub('(^| +)[^ ]*$','',data2$Description_trimmed)

    # stop if the remaining trimmed descriptions are empty
    if(all(grepl('^\\s*$',data2$Description_trimmed)))
        break
}

data2
#>   Id             Description Actual Description_trimmed Results
#> 1  1           Chiquita mini     24                        Good
#> 2  2       Chiquita Oriville    110                        Good
#> 3  3            Chiquita 24h     80                        Good
#> 4  4     Manzano Chiquita 5j     90                        <NA>
#> 5  5  Chiquita mazamorra 12h    134                       Small
#> 6  6 Chiquita mazamorra Buro    123                        Good
#> 7  7          Chiquita AM 2F    210                       Small
```

(BTY, this solution calculates `is.na(data$Results)` twice per loop, whereas you only really need to calculate it once - I was going for ease of reading not efficiency in this aspect...)

Comment: tried your solution the code is going into an infinite loop, also I am confused with some variables you referenced in the proposed solution for example data$Results ?? I am assuming this is data2$Results :)

Comment: :) that fix worked, but the logic dosent pick up cases where Description has trailing ...... for instance row 8, Data2, since this observation belongs to rule 1 in data1 (data1, row1), I was hoping the results would show small or good but right now it shows NA :) , similarly when there is a , in between which is row 10 data2. I apologize this is a very wild dataset and I am very thankful for help.

Comment: You will have to tailor the regular expressions to your dataset. For example, substituting `'\\s+\\d.*$'` for `'\\s+[0-9.].*$'` might help with the trailing `'...'` problem.  I suggest trying out https://regex101.com/ and testing some expressions with the strings that are giving you fits.   :)